# How to keep the razorpay id secret in the html that is being passed as a context for processing the payment?

Tags: django, django-views, payment, razorpay

I am using an **.env** file to keep the variables out of the **settings.py** but the **razorpay_id** that is supposed to be a secret can still be seen by inspecting the element of the page in which the id is being passed in the context. How I can keep it a "secret" or what is the process to keep that id a "secret" in the html too during the entire payment process. this is the codes that I am using.

**.env**

```
RAZORPAY_ID=test_id
RAZORPAY_ACCOUNT_ID=test_id
```

**settings.py**

```
RAZORPAY_ID = env('RAZORPAY_ID')
RAZORPAY_ACCOUNT_ID = env('RAZORPAY_ACCOUNT_ID')
```

**views.py**

```
client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZORPAY_ID , settings.RAZORPAY_ACCOUNT_ID))

context={
    'razorpay_merchant_id': settings.RAZORPAY_ID,

}
```

**html**

```
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "{{razorpay_merchant_id}}",
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, you can't do that because razorpay SDK required that and there is no other way you can hide that in browser you can [minify](https://www.toptal.com/developers/javascript-minifier/) your javascript so it will difficult to read or you can try razorpay [API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Okay, is that risky to expose that Id? Do all sites expose this Id like this only ?

Comment: Hello @Ritankar Bhattacharjee No, I think there is no security issue if it's there so razorpay will not recomend that in it's doc. I don't know about all sites but razorpay use that in there [demo](https://razorpay.com/demo/)